# Who "erwirtschaftet" what?

Tags: verb, accusative, nominative

Erdöl erwirtschaftet den größten Teil der gesamten Wirtschaft von Aserbaidschan.

Given that erwirtschaften means to obtain by careful management, this sentence makes no sense, because it would appear that the Erdöl is doing the obtaining. And yet Pons.com, Collinsdictionary.com fail to clarify this usage. Or does der größten Teil der gesamten Wirtschaft von Aserbaidschan obtain Erdöl? I guess that would be it, and they just put a den instead of a der.

(https://en.pons.com/translate/german-english/erwirtschaften)
(https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/erwirtschaften)

Source: https://www.kinderweltreise.de/kontinente/asien/aserbaidschan/laenderraetsel/

Comment: This seems sloppily phrased; I assume, it is supposed to simply mean *Der größte Teil der Wirtschaft von Aserbaidschan beruht auf Erdöl*.

Comment: I think there are more reliable on-line dictionaries out there than Pons or Collins. In general I get very suspicious when there is more space devoted to banner ads than to defining the word. For the most complete information you should probably use a German-German dictionary such as DWDS.

Comment: Das ist schlechter Stil. Das Erdöl ist ja nicht selber aktiv und macht etwas. Der Satz in dem ersten Kommentar oben drückt die Sache viel besser aus.

Comment: I believe this is maybe a case of a [Metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) where "Erdöl" stands in for "Erdölindustie".

Comment: Journalists prefer concise headlines rather than correct syntax and grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Your asked sentence is just another way of saying "Durch Erdöl wird der größte Teil der gesamten Wirtschaft von Aserbaidschan erwirtschaftet.". But the original text is also possible which means it is not wrong, although the style is pretty colloquial because it somehow implies the questions you have and assumes people get the connection by understanding from context and know what the indicated picture means.

Comment: Saying that the "Wirtschaft" gets "erwirtschaftet" still sounds rather silly

Comment: @Lykanion That's why I wrote "pretty colloquial". This is friendly for "bad style".

Answer (score 0):

"Erdöl erwirtschaftet den größten Teil der gesamten Wirtschaft von Aserbaidschan."

One can can understand what the sentence intends to say (oil production has the largest share in Azerbaijan's economy), but it is awful German.

The verb "erwirtschaften" is attributed to persons or companies generating a certain output, not to raw materials like oil. It usually occurs in the phrase "einen Gewinn erwirtschaften" which means to make a profit.

The complete phrase "Erdöl erwirtschaftet den größten Teil der gesamten Wirtschaft" is *really* awful. The literal translation would be something like "oil generates the largest share of the whole economy". As mentioned above, "erwirtschaften" refers to some concrete result, not to an abstractum like "economy". Moreover, even if the sentence would be correct semantically, the combination of *erwirtschaften* and *Wirtschaft* has a terrible sound and would be a stylistical mistake.